# How to fix Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure in Jenkins on AWS EC2

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, amazon-ec2

When running a Jenkins pipeline on an AWS EC2 instance, it is taking a very long time, and some test cases are getting skipped when executing 50 test cases at once from Git. However, in my local environment, all the test cases successfully execute within 30 minutes. The error specifically occurs on an AWS EC2 Windows instance.

Below is my error log on Jenkins console:

'<<< FAILURE!
<**org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: >
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.**
Host info: host: 'EC2AMAZ-MQG092E', ip: '10.1.1.6'
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:620)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:163)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:72)
at org.basepackage.VBaseClass.launch(VBaseClass.java:153)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:700)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:527)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.*
** Build info: version: '4.12.0', revision: '249f2a7d1b*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2022', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.21'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver**
*at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:119)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.12.0', revision: '249f2a7d1b*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2022', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.21'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2024)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:230)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.12.0', revision: '249f2a7d1b*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2022', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.21'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:263)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.lambda$start$1(DriverService.java:209)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:22711/status] to be available after 21596 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:259)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:91)
... 6 more

```
**[ERROR] Surefire is going to kill self fork JVM. The exit has elapsed 30 seconds after System.exit(0).**'
```